# most efficient way to evaluate tensorflow Tensor on multiple input

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose the following example where the tensor `y` is evaluated for several values of `x`

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 30])
w = tf.random_uniform((30, 100), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(x, w))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)

ris = []
for i in range(100):
    X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (200, 30))
    ris.append(y.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x:X}))

print(ris)
```

I am wondering if the several calls to `y.eval()` can slow down the process and if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do evaluation for multiple values is to put them in one batch and evaluate them in a single call to eval(). In your code you create 100 minibatches of size 200 -- if you want a fast evaluation, why not use a single batch of 100*200? In some cases that might cause memory problems, but I think that would be the first thing to try for speed.

Comment: That's true but I am afraid that I would run in memory issues. I'll wait for a better answer. I would accept this if noone shows up